# The device.connect() function is not working as expected in twilio javascript voice sdk

Tags: twilio, twilio-click-to-call

I'm getting this error when calling device.connect() function in `@twilio/voice-sdk` like

```
device.connect({
      params: {
          To: '+91---------',
      }
    })
```

TypeError: 'get' on proxy: property '_log' is a read-only and non-configurable data property on the proxy target but the proxy did not return its actual value (expected '#' but got '#')

I was expecting the call to placed but the call UI was not responding and the the call didn't happen

Comment: Can you please share more code to have a minimal reproducible example of that error?